# Converting number abbreviations (5.2k, 1.7m, etc) into valid integers with PHP

Tags: php, numbers, integer

I have a database with a column containing a variety of numbers written in "shorthand", for example:

5k for 5,000
86.6k for 86,600
4.1m for 4,100,000
1.2b for 1,200,000,000

I'd like to do some calculations with these numbers for a PHP frontend, but I need to convert them into valid integers in order to do so. How could I do this with PHP?

Comment: is this data format consistent ?

Comment: Yeah, it's consistent across the whole dataset

Comment: i have written a solution assuming consistency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
switch (strtolower(substr($input, -1))) {
        case 'k':
                $input*=1000;
                break;
        // similarly for m, M, b, B.
}
```

Assuming your data is well-formatted. If not more check would be needed like:

```
if (!preg_match('/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?[mbk]$/i',$input)) {
   // $input is not a valid format.
}
```

Comment: In this context m is 1,000,000 so you need to update your multiple.

Comment: I'd go with a `switch(strtolower(...))`, but overall +1.

Comment: @deceze: Ya, that makes it cleaner.

Comment: You forgot to cut off the actual character before multiplying it.

Answer (score 6):

If this is your data format, and is consistent.
you can write your own function.
create a map of suffix to multiplier..
"k" => 1000, "m" => 100000

and multiply the integer value with multiplier value.
Here is a sscanf based solution :  http://codepad.org/FjwBbx1D

```
<?php

$map = array("k" => 1000,"m" => 1000000,"b" => 1000000000);
$money = "86.6k";
list($value,$suffix) = sscanf($money, "%f%s");
$final = $value*$map[$suffix];
var_dump($final);

?>
```

And here is a simple one liner:

```
<?php
$money = "86.6k";
$value = substr($money,0,-1)*pow(10,strpos("---k--m--b",substr($money,-1))) ;
var_dump($value);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Most solutions here only work for integers. This one will also work for numbers like `1.5M` or `6.83K`.

I think this function is much cleaner and more efficient

```
function formatAbbreviationToNumber($number) {
    $abbrevs = array(12 => "T", 9 => "B", 6 => "M", 3 => "K", 0 => "");

    foreach($abbrevs as $exponent => $abbrev) {
        if(strtoupper(substr($number, -1)) == $abbrev) {
            return substr_replace($number, "", -1) * pow(10, $exponent);
        }
    }
}
```

And the other way around:

```
function formatNumbertoAbbreviation($number) {
        $abbrevs = array(12 => "T", 9 => "B", 6 => "M", 3 => "K", 0 => "");

        foreach($abbrevs as $exponent => $abbrev) {
            if(abs($number) >= pow(10, $exponent)) {
                return intval($number / pow(10, $exponent)) . $abbrev;
            }
        }
    }
```

It goes up to trillion, you can add higher values if you want but make sure you put them in the array from highest to lowest.

Comment: fixed it for negative numbers as well, just needed a simple abs()

Answer (score 2):

There is a PHP function given on the manual's page of [**`ini_get()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) *(in the manual page itself -- not in the users notes)*, that does just that.

Quoting :

```
function return_bytes($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }

    return $val;
}
```

Note that this function is used to show how to convert [**shorthand byte values**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes) to integer bytes values, and, as such, considers that 1k = 1024 ; and not 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Logic to implement,
iterate through all the characters, and when you find a character (not digit) just save the index.
Now split that into two parts: digital value and character. 
Now create a function which returns the value of passed character.
eg. getValueOf('M')=1000000
And then finally do this
Numerical Value * getValueOf('M')
That's all.
Note: Your numerical values have commas in it so also do str_replace(',','',numeric value)
and then convert to int

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '5k'; // or whatever
$suffix = strspn($string, '.0123456789');
$value = doubleval(substr($string, 0, $suffix))
if($suffix < strlen($string))
{
 switch($string[$suffix])
 {
  case 'k':
   $value *= 1000;
   break;
  case 'm':
   $value *= 1000000;
   break;
  case 'b':
   $value *= 1000000000;
   break;
 }
}
echo number_format($value);
```