# Converting number abbreviations (5.2k, 1.7m, etc) into valid integers with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I have a Google Doc with a column containing a variety of numbers written in "shorthand", for example:

```
5k for 5,000
86.62k for 86,620
4.1m for 4,100,000
1.2b for 1,200,000,000
```

I'd like to do some calculations with these numbers with JavaScript (loosely used by Google Docs), but I need to convert them into valid integers in order to do so. How could I do this with JavaScript?

I see this has been done in PHP ( [Converting number abbreviations (5.2k, 1.7m, etc) into valid integers with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467694/converting-number-abbreviations-5-2k-1-7m-etc-into-valid-integers-with-php)) but not finding anything with JS.

Comment: That's pretty much the same syntax. Just remove the `$`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function convert( number )
{
  var base = parseFloat( number );
  if ( number.toLowerCase( ).match( /k/ ) )
  {
    return Math.round( base * 1000 );
  }
  else if ( number.toLowerCase( ).match( /m/ ) )
  {
    return Math.round( base * 1000000 );
  }
  else if ( number.toLowerCase( ).match( /b/ ) )
  {
    return Math.round( base * 1000000000 );
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: due to the wonders of floating point, the `4.1m` case gives you `4099999.9999999995` using this function.  You may want to use Math.round() after multipleying to end up with the proper integer result.  See jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8TERT/.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last char and check it: if 'k' multiply the rest of the string by 1000, if 'm' by one million.

Comment: Thank you! The JS works perfectly, and I think I'll go with that option because I created a crazy formula that converts M & B to integers:

=iferror(if(find("B",C69)>0,substitute(C69,"B","")*1000000000,""),substitute(C69,"M","")*1000000).

Thank you both!