# NodeJS - How to convert string currency with unit to numerical values?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to NodeJs and was wondering how do I convert a string with a recognised monetary unit to the numerical equivalent?

The units I have are `K` and `M` meaning thousands and millions, respectively. There are some values in the hundreds but I'm assuming that's just as simple as dropping the currency symbol and parsing as an int.

An example of what I wish to achieve:

The string I have says `$50K` how can I turn this into `50000`

Another string I have says `$25.5M` how do I convert this into `25500000`.

I have searched online, but the results I have got is the reserve of what I wish to achieve. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376853/converting-number-abbreviations-5-2k-1-7m-etc-into-valid-integers-with-javas